# Can nested deferred Q Promises resolves be simplified?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have combined some typical (anti-)pattern I have come along, looking at javascript using the [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

How much of this can be simplified? (or is pointless)
Especially:

- A: What is the value in `deferred.resolve(...` over returning a value and thus resolving right away? Only the fact, that code that further code get's executed, ie. `doSomeMore()` ?
- if so, for A2 this is pointless in this code?
- B: What is the value in `deferred.reject` over `throw throw new Error('')`
- C: The try-catch also irritates me. Only to ensure `doSomeMore()` ?

  function foo(u) {

  ```
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  bar(u).then( function (v) {

      if (v==42) {
          deferred.resolve( Q(null) );    // A
      } else {
          try {
              var controller = new Controller();
              deferred.resolve( controller ); // A2
          } 
          catch (error) {
              deferred.reject(error);     // B,C
          }

          doSomeMore();
      }

      return deferred.promise;
  });
  ```

  }

Comment: I'm confused as to what this code is supposed to do. Also, this code will not even parse; there's a missing end parenthesis for the `then(`.

Comment: Are you saying that you have combined the antipatterns on purpose?

Comment: @Bergi: I have _found_ them in existing code and damped down to focus on the relevant parts of issues I see...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan corrected the `)`. It's not supposed to do much, beyond fulfill (sucessfully resolve) to a Controller or Null under some circumstances, to rejection under others. — I encounter such thing things (in less abstract form of course) in production code, thus seeking a better understanding for (anti)patterns and practices...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the purpose of this code seems to be ensuring that `doSomeMore()` is executed regardless what happened when the `Controller` was constructed. You could get that more easily though:

```
function foo(u) {
    return bar(u).then(function (v) {
        if (v == 42) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                return new Controller();
            } finally {
                doSomeMore();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @jfriend00: Yes, `finally` does *always* execute, that's its entire point :-)

Comment: `return null` is just as good as `deferred.resolve( Q(null) );`? (That's what I was thinking, too)

Comment: @FrankN: Yes, pretty much (assuming that `deferred` doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
return bar(u).then(function (v) {      
  if (v==42) 
    return null;  
  return new Controller();  
}).finally(function() { doSomeMore(); });
```

Comment: As @Bergi points out this code misses the doSomeMore() only executing when v != 42.